# Corpus vs. corpse

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, differences, archaicisms

I found this definition on Wikidiff:

"The difference between corpus and corpse
is that corpus is the body while corpse is a dead body"

While in Collins and Merriam Webster I found this meaning for Corpus:

"The body of a person or animal, esp. when dead"

And at the end I don't find sentence examples using Corpus as dead body.

Comment: 'Corpus' is used to mean 'body' in a more general sense than the specific 'human body'. In general life, if someone finds a corpse, they won't say "I have found a corpus".

Comment: [This Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/corpus) calls that sense of the word 'obsolete'. It is the Latin word for a body and is used mainly in a metaphorical sense (for instance, the 'main body' of an author's work).

Comment: In *The New Oxford American Dictionary*, the first definition of *corpus* is "a collection of written texts".  It also has a medical meaning.  But it leaves out the obsolete meaning "corpse".

Comment: A corpus from Latin meaning body is a grouping of something in English, not a dead body.